# How do foreign keys work in this possible M:M relationship?

Tags: sql, database, erd

In my ER diagram, I have a big table called "EVENT" that roughly looks like this:

```
EVENT_ID: INTEGER

USER_ID: USER

EVENT_TYPE: VARCHAR

SCREEN_ID: SCREEN

BUTTON_ID: BUTTON

TIMESTAMP: DATETIME
```

The USER table contains user data, the BUTTON table contains the name and the location on screen of the button. Event types are things like viewing a screen or clicking a button.

There are various categories of screens. One of them is called "Lessons", which contains more "Exams", each "Exam" containing more questions. So my SCREEN table (1:1 relationship with itself) looks like this:

```
SCREEN_ID: INTEGER

SCREEN_TYPE: VARCHAR

TIME_ON_SCREEN: INTEGER

SCREEN_URL: VARCHAR

PREVIOUS_SCREEN_ID: VARCHAR

PREVIOUS_SCREEN_URL: VARCHAR
```

There is a 1:M relationship between SCREEN and LESSON, a 1:M relationship between LESSON and EXAM, and a 1:M relationship from EXAM to QUESTION.

**The problem is, a single question contains more screens because first it shows the question and after I answer an explanation follows. So even if the question ID is the same, the screen ID changes.** How do I represent this relationship in the diagram and what happens to the SCREEN_ID key? Will it become a foreign key in QUESTION?

Comment: It's unclear to me why you would have a screen in an entity diagram. Presentation layer elements do not belong in an entity diagram.

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison I thought it works the same way as the button, since  I am interested in the screens that were viewed and how much time each user spent on every screen,.. So should I just put the lessons, exams, and questions and connect them directly to the event?

Comment: It's unclear to me why the button is in the entity diagram as well. It's clear you're tracking analytics but there is probably a better way of doing so. In a nutshell there is no guarantee that a question will be on one screen - and only one screen. You're trying to tie data elements with presentation elements. You could just trap the actual events and that would give enough data - especially if you tie in the window title and dynamically change the window title when a new question is loaded.

Comment: If you want someone to sort out the SQL relationships I suggest adding in some schema SQL statements, some SQL dummy data statements - show the SQL you're running with the results your getting - and give some sample results of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys work in a M:M relationship using a link table.

Consider
Customers and Videos - this is a many to many relationship.

Three tables

customer
video
customer_video

customer 1:M customer_video

video 1:M customer_video

customer M:M video